# create linked server without management studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, linked-server

I've installed Microsoft SQL Server 2008 and only got the Database Engine, not sure what to do with it.

Is it possible to create linked server without Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio? Without the MSSMS, there is no GUI to create the linked server, so it could be script or command I guess. So how should I do it?

Comment: You can run sp_addlinkedserver (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedserver-transact-sql) using the SQLCMD command-prompt utility (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why choose? For as long as I can remember (going back to SSMS 2005), most dialogs have had a script button on them. So fill out the form and instead of hitting okay, hit the Script button and SSMS will show you the commands it would have ran. I often use this as a boostrap when I'm doing something I haven't done before. That is, I'll fill in the wizard, hit the script button, and then read the docs to see if I agree with everything it's doing.

[image: Add linked server wizard]

Comment: Ya provided that you have the SSMS, my client don't have it and I'm unable to install anything in their server so I need an alternative to that. Guess I'll go with the SQLCMD way.

Comment: With Developer Edition of SQL Server being free these days, install a local instance on your workstation and go through the motions of creating the linked server you want. Then hit that Script button and apply the resulting script to the server you want.